# ScalaPb sbt: Import "data/common/num.proto" was not found or had errors

Tags: scala, sbt, scalapb

My project structure is:

```
logs
 - data
     - pubs
       - invent.proto
     - common
       - num.proto
```

NOTE - The .proto files are not under `src/main/protobuf`. They're under a directory called `logs` directly under project

In `invent.proto`, I have `import "data/common/num.proto";`

My build.sbt is:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

libraryDependencies += "com.thesamet.scalapb" %% "scalapb-runtime" % scalapb.compiler.Version.scalapbVersion % "protobuf"

PB.includePaths in Compile := Seq(
  baseDirectory.value / "logs"
)

excludeFilter in PB.generate := "test-*.proto"

PB.targets in Compile := Seq(
  scalapb.gen() -> baseDirectory.value/"src/main/scala"
)
```

When I compile, I get the below error:

```
data/common/num.proto: File not found.
data/pubs/invent.proto: Import "data/common/num.proto" was not found or had errors.
```

How can I solve this issue? I'm not trying to import external .proto files. These files are present in the repo.

Comment: From the directory structure, seems like `common` isn't under `data`

Comment: @ShayNehmad My bad! I've updated the directory structure. Can you please advise how I can fix this issue?

Comment: How are you running protoc?

Comment: @ShayNehmad I've included my `build.sbt` above which uses scalapb. I run `sbt clean compile`. It compiles fine without the imports but for files with imports, it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `PB.includePaths` setting and add this instead:

```
Compile / PB.protoSources := Seq(baseDirectory.value / "logs")
```